# CSS :not() selector not working when targeting nested hierarchy

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a scenario where I want to target all tables (or any element) in the page / a container except those elements inside a special container or class (for 
example .exempt-table) .

I tried it using `:not()` selector to target "All tables except those inside `.exempt-table`" as follows:

```
.container :not(.exempt-table) table { 
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here is the complete example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

div::before {
  content: 'DIV';
}

.container :not(.exempt-table) table {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>General Table. Table1</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="exempt-table">
        <h1>Special Table. Table2</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td>COl1</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>NESTED: General Table. Table3</h1>
        <div>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="exempt-table">
        <h1>NESTED: Special Table. Table4</h1>
        <div >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td>COl1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expectation is, `border` (red) should not be applied to **Table2**, **Table4** because these tables are inside `.exempt-table`. But, the border applied to all tables except **Table2** because **Table2** is direct child if `.container` where as Table4 is just descendant.

**27th Nov:**
Updated the above example to address the issue with `> table`.

Comment: you will need two selector for this

Comment: Table 4 is also in a div without a class, which is a match for `:not(.exempt-table)`. So you should avoid situations like those. You can use `:not(.exempt-table) > table` here.

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif unlike the duplicated question where styles overridden, I dont the border to be applied at all for tables inside ".exempt-table' instead of applying to all and override again. Hope this make sense.

Comment: the duplicate explain that you cannot do this using one selector, that's why I added it as a duplicate. You can also follow the duplicate of the duplicate for more details

Answer (score -1):

**please try this style**

```
<style>
      .container :not(.exempt-table) > table {
        border: 5px solid red;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this working, but, this needs table to be immediate child of .exempt-table which may not be guaranteed in my case

Comment: @PrasannaKumar: This CSS code also work for more table please check

Comment: this is not working in case of <div class="exempt-table"> <div> <table> because  table is not direct child of ".exempt-table"